# Banach–Tarski n sphere

Tags: homology-sphere

[The Banach Tarski Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Tarski_paradox) as applies for 3 sphere.

Is there a solution for Banach–Tarski paradox for n sphere?
or in particular for 5 sphere, and if so what is the general solution?

Comment: do you have a reference to the general solution?